# How to use regular expression to get a link inside a Script with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

This is my code:

```
videoresponse = s.get("https://platzi.com/clases/1272-sql-mysql/11085-bienvenidos-al-curso9999/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(videoresponse.content,'html5lib')
scripts = soup.findAll('hls')
print(scripts)#It doesnt works, just prints []
```

It contains a response with some `<script></script>` tags. One of them has this piece of code:

```
 iframes: [],
 videos: {"serverA": {"id": "serverA", "hls": "https://movin-b.platzi.com/080e9d74-4dbe-4de8-baa5-1fe3ae97f8a9/5ae7e0dee883414be4a13216.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl,audio-only=false)", "dash": "https://movin-b.platzi.com/080e9d74-4dbe-4de8-baa5-1fe3ae97f8a9/5ae7e0dee883414be4a13216.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)"}, "serverB": {"id": "serverB", "hls": "https://movin.platzi.com/080e9d74-4dbe-4de8-baa5-1fe3ae97f8a9/5ae7e0dee883414be4a13216.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl,audio-only=false)", "dash": "https://movin.platzi.com/080e9d74-4dbe-4de8-baa5-1fe3ae97f8a9/5ae7e0dee883414be4a13216.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)"}, "serverC": {"id": "serverC", "hls": "https://mdstrm.com/video/5ae7e0dee883414be4a13216.m3u8"}},
```

And I need to extract the links with: "m3u8" or in other words the hls's values. In all the response there are only three "HLS": and "m3u8", so, trying with BeautifulSoup I found that it only works with HTML tags, or in this case, with Regular Expresions, but I dont know how to use it.

With this I am going to make an array with the m3u8 link in the response, because sometimes there are less than 3 servers availables for the video.

I will appreciate if you can tell me how to make the re, I know I need to import the re module but I dont know how to make the regular expresion for use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this way, just use python standard **json** api as below

```
import json
test = """{"serverA": {"id": "serverA", "hls": "https://movin-b.platzi.com/080e9d74-4dbe-4de8-baa5-1fe3ae97f8a9/5ae7e0dee883414be4a13216.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl,audio-only=false)", "dash": "https://movin-b.platzi.com/080e9d74-4dbe-4de8-baa5-1fe3ae97f8a9/5ae7e0dee883414be4a13216.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)"}, "serverB": {"id": "serverB", "hls": "https://movin.platzi.com/080e9d74-4dbe-4de8-baa5-1fe3ae97f8a9/5ae7e0dee883414be4a13216.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl,audio-only=false)", "dash": "https://movin.platzi.com/080e9d74-4dbe-4de8-baa5-1fe3ae97f8a9/5ae7e0dee883414be4a13216.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)"}, "serverC": {"id": "serverC", "hls": "https://mdstrm.com/video/5ae7e0dee883414be4a13216.m3u8"}}"""
all_servers = json.loads(test)
for server_key in all_servers:
    print(all_servers[server_key]["hls"])
```

Here is the console output

> ```
> > https://movin-b.platzi.com/080e9d74-4dbe-4de8-baa5-1fe3ae97f8a9/5ae7e0dee883414be4a13216.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl,audio-only=false)
> > https://movin.platzi.com/080e9d74-4dbe-4de8-baa5-1fe3ae97f8a9/5ae7e0dee883414be4a13216.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl,audio-only=false)
> > https://mdstrm.com/video/5ae7e0dee883414be4a13216.m3u8
> ```

Comment: `videoresponse = s.get("https://platzi.com/clases/1272-sql-mysql/11085-bienvenidos-al-curso9999/") 
    all_servers = json.loads(videoresponse.content)
    for server_key in all_servers:
        print(all_servers[server_key]["hls"])` I did that, and get this error: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 7 column 1 (char 6)` How can I Fix it? why yours works?